# How to set focus to edit box in custom ui ribbon without sending keys in VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, ribbon-control, ribbonx

I have 9 edit boxes which are to be filled in a certain order, and are usually filled consecutively. However, the only way I currently know how to move from edit box to edit box is either a mouse click or *Send Keys* commands. Using this is not an efficient way to move from edit box to edit box

I am using Windows 7 with Excel 2010.

The Excel Workbook is an .xltm.

I wrote the XML using *Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office*.

I know how to write call back functions, and have several working callbacks.

I have looked on a large number of threads, but none of them have given me any idea as how to do what I need to.

I am aware that my code below to activate/set focus to the next edit box is not correct, if it were, I would not be asking the question.

## Code Example

### VBA:

> ```
>   OC STANDS FOR ON CHANGE
>   GT STANDS FOR GET TEXT
>   CB STANDS FOR CONTROL BOX
> ```

```
Public Sub VOL1_OC_CB(IRIB As IRibbonControl, ByRef text)
    'CODE TO EDIT WORKSHEET'
    IRibbonControls("VOL1").ACTIVATE
End Sub

Public Sub VOL1_GT_CB(IRIB As IRibbonControl, ByRef text)
    'CODE TO SET EDIT BOX VALUE AT STARTUP'
End Sub

Public Sub VOL2_OC_CB(IRIB As IRibbonControl, ByRef text)
    'CODE TO EDIT WORKSHEET'    
    IRibbonControls("PCNT").ACTIVATE
End Sub

Public Sub VOL2_GT_CB(IRIB As IRibbonControl, ByRef text)
    'CODE TO SET EDIT BOX VALUE AT STARTUP'
End Sub

Public Sub PCT_OC_CB(IRIB As IRibbonControl, ByRef text)
    'CODE TO EDIT WORKSHEET'
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").Activate
End Sub

Public Sub PCT_GT_CB(IRIB As IRibbonControl, ByRef text)
    'CODE TO SET EDIT BOX VALUE AT STARTUP'
End Sub
```

### XML:

```
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id="OBR" label="OBR" keytip="CD">
                <group id="MOQS" label="MOQs">
                    <editBox id="VOL1" label="VOL 1"
                        getText="VOL1_GT_CB" onChange="VOL1_OC_CB" keytip="V1"/>
                    <editBox id="VOL2" label="VOL 2"
                        getText="VOL2_GT_CB" onChange="VOL2_OC_CB" keytip="V2"/>
                </group>
                <group id="val" label="values">
                    <editBox id="PCNT" label="INCREASE  %"
                        getText="PCT_GT_CB" onChange="PCT_OC_CB" keytip="PCT"/>
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
```

I expect that on changing Edit Box *VOL1* that Edit Box *VOL2* will receive the focus/activate, but when I change *VOL1* it activates the sheet instead.

Also, I apologize if my formatting and phrasings are awkward, I am not very good at communicating, and tend to make odd language choices. The same goes with the way I name functions and variables.

Comment: The only way it could be possible would be to work with the Accessibility APIs. You might find this helpful to get an idea of what is involved: http://wordarticles.com/Shorts/RibbonVBA/RibbonVBADemo.htm Note that since this was written Microsoft has introduced a new accessibility interface, so documentation has been weeded out. I don't know how/if it's possible to work with the new APIs using VBA.

Comment: The solution provided helps a bit, but does not guide me towards the correct answer, because it only lists the values, it does not activate the controls for the user to enter data.,

Comment: I did see something about using CommandBar, but I am unsure if those are the same thing.

Comment: The CommandBar object model refers to the old, pre-Ribbon toolbars. There are a limited number of methods added to it to work with the Ribbon, but none that select or move to a control. There's one to execute a control, the rest are "get" methods to determine state.

Comment: Ok, as of now I have resolved myself to create a user form and do fulfill my goal that way.